# suck2blow reference?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i usually use rosawesome aliases to shortcut commands in the terminal. suck2blow is an alias for 'rosbag record', but why? Is it a reference to something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285116/suck2blow-reference?/) by [nmssilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/34098/nmssilva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See #q45463 and #q277428 for a related questions, and as a shortcut, see [ROSCon 2012 - Lightning Talks - What does rosawesome do?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPSyW1zGarA&t=40s) for probably a rather authoritative source (spoiler: they're [Spaceballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceballs) references).

---

Edit:

> I asked if suck2blow a reference to something.

Yes. Again, to Spaceballs: [Spaceballs "Mega Maid" scene](https://youtu.be/O7aeWQCF1jM?t=260).

> What's the meaning of suck2blow and why is it linked with rosbag play?

Mega Maid (from [Mega_Maid](http://spaceballs.wikia.com/wiki/Mega_Maid)):

> Mega Maid is the transformed version of Spaceball I. It is shaped like a woman with a vacuum cleaner. The vacuum can both suck air out of a planet's atmosphere, and blow it back into an atmosphere. It appears very powerful, since it can clean a mountain of snow, and pull a forest's trees straight out of the ground (and put everything back neatly if set in reverse).

So `rosbag` first 'sucks' (records) and then 'blows' (plays back).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nmssilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/34098/nmssilva/) on 2018-03-12**:
yes i've seen those and you haven't answered my question. I asked if suck2blow a reference to something. Like an easter egg. What's the meaning of suck2blow and why is it linked with rosbag play?